# How can I iterate a scala collection using a loop?

Tags: scala

I know I can use the *x.foreach{ ... }* syntax, but I want to explicity use a loop. How can I do that in Scala? I tried to use the following code, but it complains that *hasNext* and *next* are not members of the *Iterable[T]*.

```
while (it.hasNext)
  println("\t" + it.next.toString())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
val iter = it.iterator
while (iter.hasNext) {
  println("\t" + iter.next.toString())
}
```

Comment: as Gregor Raýman noted, it is not a good way in Scala, there are a lot of methods to iterate through collection, use foreach, map, foldLeft or something else depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

`Iterable` does not have `next` nor `hasNext`, `Iterator` has.

So your code needs to change to something like this:

```
val i = it.iterator
while (i.hasNext) println("\t" + i.next.toString())
```

Note however that this is not idiomatic Scala at all.

You could achieve the same with `println(it.mkString("\t","\t",""))`

Comment: Although it is idiomatic *optimized Scala*. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider also `map`,

```
it.iterator.map(i => "\t" + i.toString())
```

as well as a for comprehension,

```
for (i <- it.iterator) yield "\t" + i.toString()
```